# If two languages are decidable, can one be mapping reducible to the other?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, reductions

If I have two decidable languages $A$ and $B$, is $A \leq_m B$ true? How would I show this?

Comment: What if $B = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is false. Consider for example the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ and the two languages $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \Sigma^*$.

Clearly both $A$ and $B$ are decidable (by the trivial algorithms that always reject and always acccept, respectively) but it is false that $A \le_m B$.